# How do I test a Magento project using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I Perform testing in a Magento project using selenium web driver?

Comment: Selenium webdriver is not project specific. It supports all web applications. You just need to define your strategies based on your project needs.

Comment: I am new to Testing...My company has developing an e-commerce website using Magento...so Is there any special thing added to test the website developed by magento....

Comment: I see , please see my answer. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For common magento website you can automate following things :

1. Login / Register with diff. Users
2. Email Id verification while login / register
3. Add to cart product and verify product count in cart
4. Remove product from cart
5. Automate checkout process
6. Verify billing and shipping address forms validations
7. Verify header / footer text
8. Payment gateway automation
9. Product listing counts and elements verification

Above are common test cases which you can automate for magento website. After that depends on your customization things.

You can start to learn selenium driver from [Here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: Thanks... Is there necessary to install MAGENTO TESTING FRAMEWORK for test the website develped by Magento...or using selenium is Enough for that?..

Comment: No need. Because selenium directly interact with web browsers so will work with front website.

Comment: Yes Selenium web driver is enough. Then you can use some more supported tools to enhance it. But you at initial level selenium webdriver is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is definitely useful to get started but there is a lot of automation to build out.  Magium is an open source library that you can use for this kind of functionality.  It is built on top of Selenium but basically abstracts away much of the busy-work.

For example, building out a test that starts at the home page and goes all the way through checkout looks like this.

```
class GuestCheckoutTest extends AbstractMagentoTestCase
{

    public function testBasicCheckout()
    {
        $this->commandOpen($this->getTheme()->getBaseUrl());
        $this->getNavigator(DefaultSimpleProductCategory::NAVIGATOR)->navigateTo();
        $this->getNavigator(DefaultSimpleProduct::NAVIGATOR)->navigateTo();
        $this->getAction(AddSimpleProductToCart::ACTION)->execute();        
        $this->setPaymentMethod('CashOnDelivery');
        $guestCheckout = $this->getAction(GuestCheckout::ACTION);
        /* @var $guestCheckout \Magium\Magento\Actions\Checkout\GuestCheckout */

        $guestCheckout->execute();

        $orderId = $this->getExtractor(OrderId::EXTRACTOR);
        /** @var $orderId OrderId */
        self::assertNotNull($orderId->getOrderId());
        self::assertGreaterThan(0, $orderId->getOrderId());
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not actively maintaining it anymore.

Comment: thx for your reply and for your effort, i'll try to use it :)